# self-invoking constructor in JS

Tags: javascript

Since I want to enforce *new*, I create the constructor like following. It works fine, even I do NOT call the constructor with ***new***, the instance can still get the property. But I confused that since in the if statement, it already **return**, why the statements below if statement can be invoked?

```
function Car(){
    if(!(this instanceof Car)){
        return new Car();
        console.log("can i arrive here?");
    }
    this.tires = "I have four tires";
    console.log("yeah,I can arrive here");
}

//Note: without new
var car = Car();//output=> yeah,I can arrive here
console.log(car.tires);//output => I have four tires
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are **two** calls to `Car` in this code. The first one:

```
var car = Car();
```

results in a second call:

```
return new Car();
```

The **second** call executes `console.log("yeah,I can arrive here");`. The first call never runs that line. Otherwise, you'd see the output twice.

Comment: I forget in the if statement call the new Car() :)

Answer (score 0):

things to know

one: the code between `{` and `}` doesnt execute in a `if` statement that returns false.

two: `return` exit's a function.

```
var iAmRight = true;

function checkAwesome(){

   if ( !iAmRight ){
      return "i never arrived here";
      return "even if i wasent awesome i wouldnt arrive here";
   }
   //so therefore you can

   return "i am awesome";

}

checkAwesome();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `return new Car()` is being executed. Just put `console.log("can i arrive here?");` before `return new Car();`